Is there a reliable way to know whether a keybinding is already in use?
When making a custom keybinding, it's always in the back of my mind that I might be conflicting with some other keybinding, especially one from a (not loaded) plugin. Hence the act of pressing the keybinding to see if it currently does anything won't guarantee that it's available.
Is there any way to definitively know for a given Vim/Neovim setup (config plus plugins) whether a specific keybinding would conflict with any other?

In addition to the great answers below, you might also be interested in :help map-which-keys.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

You can use :help maparg() to get information on a specific mapping (or abbreviation) and :help maplist() to get a list of all mappings (or abbreviations). Both can be used to condition a mapping.
For example, with maparg():
if maparg('<S-Tab>', 'c', 0, 1)->empty()
    cnoremap <expr> <S-Tab> getcmdtype() =~ '[\/?]' ? "<C-t>" : "<S-Tab>" 
endif

where we check if there is already something mapped to <S-Tab> in command-line mode before doing our mapping.
Note that the built-in commands, like w in normal mode or <C-a> in insert mode (just a couple of examples from the top of my head, the list is huge, see :help index), ARE NOT MAPPINGS and therefore can't be "checked" before creating a custom mapping. The two functions mentioned above only work for actual mappings.
Note also that, as was pointed out in the other answer, a mapping defined in a script that hasn't been sourced is a mapping that doesn't exist. Vim can only know about mappings that exist in memory at the time you call maparg()/maplist() or do :map, so you will have to put a bit of effort into writing your own function that scans your :help 'runtimepath' in search of mappings if you want to cover all your bases. And even then, you will have to take filetype plugins into account, which makes it a little bit more complex.
And then, there is the problem of <leader> which is expanded when the map <leader>… command is executed, with the current value of :help mapleader. The mapping is registered with the expanded <leader>, not the string <leader>, and <leader> can change value between two expansions anyway, so <leader> mappings are hard to check reliably.
Now, opinions…
Your concerns may kind of vaguely make sense from a plugin authorship perspective but, even then, the right thing to do is to expose <Plug> mappings and let the user create their own mappings anyway. Forcing mappings on your users is not exactly a good practice.
From a user perspective, worrying about overriding existing mappings (or even existing built-in commands) is largely pointless. As a user, I know the mappings I use so there is zero chance that I willingly or unwillingly override any of them. If I accidentally override a mapping I don't know, it means that I never used it in the first place: the override will have zero impact on my workflow, therefore it is harmless and I don't have to check anything.

I thought about writing an answer to the effect of your last paragraph, I upvoted instead. I find it helpful to be as close as possible to the target environment. E.g. when thinking about a mapping for Python, do :edit foo.py and be reasonably sure that filetype plugins, autocommands, etc. have fired.

Typo? arglist instead of maplist in the first paragraph

Faulty chain of thoughts: "maparg" > "arglist". Fixed.

If it is not loaded there no ways since Vim has no information about the plugin.
But if it is you can get a list of all the mapping for a given prefix with the map command.
e.g.:
The following command list all mapping that starts with m in normal mode:
:nmap m

Remark: the mapping can be buffer specific (typically some filetyoe mapping). You should run the command on a buffer of the filetyoe for which you would like to introduce the mapping.
Remark: the command will not liist the builtin mapping. Actually Vim use nearly all keys for commands (see this answer for the list of free keys) and a fair fraction of key pairs combination (see available key pairs from @romainl)
A common recommendation is to use mapping that starts with the <leader> key or the <localleader> key to limit conflict.
Remark: the default value of the <leader> key is \ if you start using mapping that starts with it you maybe interested to change that. Popular choice for the <leader> key are Space or ,.
